# Ruby / MySQL fetching single row but still using .each?

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

I'm using the [MySQL2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) Ruby driver - but it seems a bit redundant having to call

```
result.each{ |r| puts r['name'] }
```

for a single row of data that is returned. There must be a simpler way to get the mysql field I want without having to use the `each` block?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `result` should be a [`Mysql2::Result`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/Mysql2/Result) and that's [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) so you can use [`first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-first) (and the rest of the `Enumerable` goodies) on it:

```
puts result.first['name']
```