# Mysql2 strategy for setting local variables for select limit 1

Tags: ruby, mysql2

learning ruby (or trying.)

I'm using the Mysql2 gem to query data that I know will only return one record (LIMIT 1.) However, Mysql2 returns a Mysql2::Result which I have to iterate to get my value:

```
client2.query("SELECT `Parent_ID`,`Path` FROM `Categories` WHERE (`ID` = 83) LIMIT 1").each do |row|
      local_var = row['Path']
    end
```

Of course, local_var is not in scope so this method doesn't set the variable to use outside of the loop in the rest of the script.

It shouldn't be this hard. :)

1. Is there a way to get a single result from Mysql2 that doesn't involve a loop iteration?
2. If not, how can I set a local variable (or some other global object value) to store the result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the following answer:

[Ruby / MySQL fetching single row but still using .each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064649/ruby-mysql-fetching-single-row-but-still-using-each)

No loop necessary. Just call first on Mysql2::Result

```
local_var = row.first['Path']
```

Comment: Ha ha, I knew this question seemed familiar! Keep in mind that [`MySQL2::Result`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/Mysql2/Result) includes [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html) so you have access to the rest of the `Enumerable` goodies too.

Comment: Yeah, that makes tons of sense now. Not coming from a ruby world, I was a bit lost there.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is how to get a Model instead of an array of models?

Model

If you need the name:

```
Category.find(83).name
```

Array of models

If you need the name of each one:

```
# Find by the ID
Category.all.each do |result|
   result.name
end

# Find by one attribute
Category.find_all_by_cod(83).each do |result|
   result.name
end
```

Comment: Actually, no. Thanks for the answer though. Will probably help someone else. I am currently using Sequel.